# Combining JTextarea output of another class to the JTextArea of main class frame?

Tags: java, swing, layout, textarea

I have one class that displays the output into a JTextArea. Meaning after successful run, it will display the output in a text area.

I have also one main class that combines classes together with several buttons to initiate execution of code in specific classes. This main class creates a GUI with several buttons.  Now  I need the above JTextArea to incorporated into the main frame.

How do I do this?

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://pscode.org/sscce.html).

Answer (score 1):

Using a (possibly nested) Layout.  See [Using Layout Managers](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/using.html) in the Java Tutorial for further details.